# React Native app keeps stopping after react-native-gesture-handler install

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

Recently I started an app with React Native 0.60, the first build worked fine, but when after installing and configuring react-native-gesture-handler the app keeps stoping in my emulator. It gives no error, simply keeps stopping. The only change I made was adding those packages.

This is my MainActivity.java with the gesture handler required config

```java
package com.ggwp;

import com.facebook.react.ReactActivity;
import com.facebook.react.ReactActivityDelegate;
import com.facebook.react.ReactRootView;
import com.swmansion.gesturehandler.react.RNGestureHandlerEnabledRootView;

public class MainActivity extends ReactActivity {

    /**
     * Returns the name of the main component registered from JavaScript.
     * This is used to schedule rendering of the component.
     */
    @Override
    protected String getMainComponentName() {
        return "ggWP";
    }

      @Override
      protected ReactActivityDelegate createReactActivityDelegate() {
        return new ReactActivityDelegate(this, getMainComponentName()) {
          @Override
          protected ReactRootView createRootView() {
           return new RNGestureHandlerEnabledRootView(MainActivity.this);
          }
        };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be realted to migration related to `AndroidX` which started after `react native version 0.60+`

You might have to `install jetifier` by then `npx Jetify` which will load the androidX libraries.

Also try removing the node modules folder and then installing them again. Relink the gesture handler library and then add androidX migration tools and some tweek in gradle.properties to use the androidX library.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, but it's the same. I intalled all my modules again, used jetifier, and the app keeps stopping. I don't know what else to do.

Comment: downgrade the version of react native gesture handler